# Evaluate k adjacent (plus or minus) elements within array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been struggling with the task of having an inequality threshold imposed on `k` adjacent elements within a 1 dimensional numpy array -- I should add, both to the left and to the right. For example:

```
if x[i+-100] < .05:
```

That is as best as I can articulate it, obviously it doesn't work. But I hope my point is clearer. In other words, I would like to discern if any elements within plus or minus 100 elements of element x are of a value greater than .05. Here is my whole function for context: (here I have -.05 as well)

```
def vector_recode(x):
    if (x[i+-100]) > .05 or (x[i+-100]) < -.05:
        return X
    else:
        return 0
recode_function = np.vectorize(vector_recode)
```

--For clarity, the above function is trying to take values that are close enough to zero and flush them to zero, or if there are any nearby [+-100] elements that are of a value higher that .05 in absolute terms, keep x as is.

I have a sinking feeling that I might have to resort to for looping, but np has always surprised me with its efficiency, and I'm hoping someone has insight that could help along me others like me dealing with `k` adjacent elements.

My other research into this procedure involves `scipy.ndimage` and convolution matrices. However I don't think that approach is easily applicable to my case -- which is simply 1D left and right neighboring elements. I have been wrong before though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If it helps I will try to do a worked out example:

```
    >>>A
[0.04,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.04]
    >>>recode_function(A)
[0,0,0,0,0]
    >>>B
[0.03,0.02,0.23,0.01,0.03]
    >>>recode_function(B)
[0.03,0.02,0.23,0.01,0.03]
```

Here lets say instead of plus or minus 100, its plus or minus 5. In array 'A' there were no values greater than .05 or less than -.05, so x and its adjacent elements would be set to zero in the vectorized function. Whereas in array 'B' there was an element greater than .05. It was 0.23, so that means the function would leave x as well as the plus or minus 5 neighboring elements of x alone. As someone rightfully pointed out, boundary elements may be need to be handled carefully. You can imagine 'A' and 'B' as two distinct arrays or partitions of 1 larger array. I'm not sure if partitioning is the way to go, but I'm open to anything. Hope this made it easier to understand.

Comment: what to do with boundary elements that don't have 100 elements to left or right?

Comment: also, if its `x[i+-100]) > .05`, won't it guarantee `(x[i+-100]) > -.05` too?

Comment: Good observations, I messed up the inequality signs, let me fix that. I suppose boundary elements could be handled if the element is neighbored by the value and is WITHIN 100 elements, although I'm not sure if python will throw an out of bounds error in that case as well. Thank you for your input.

Comment: My function was a little confusing, I wrote it backwards, sorry for that. It is in the correct form now. Another thought I had for boundary elements is a partition of the array from `[:x]`.

Comment: Yes, I did want an `or` there thank you. I will try to add a small example as well., thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick would be clipping the array to min-max limits at `-0.05` and `0.05` respectively and checking which elements have changed indicating that those elements were outside those min-max limits. That would result in a binary array. Then, we use binary dilation to extend this *ANY* lookup to a certain a window size. Finally, based on the extended mask, we use `np.where` to choose between keeping original elements or set to 0.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

def reset_arr(x, W, T): # x: input array, W : window size, T : threshold as +-
    mask = binary_dilation(x.clip(min=-T, max=T) != x,np.ones(2*W+1))
    return np.where(mask, x, 0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [376]: x
Out[376]: 
array([ 0.06821936,  0.66300942,  0.15449635,  1.52260898,  0.41346868,
       -0.48343499,  0.45386276,  2.1888203 ,  0.36947105, -0.17660172])

In [377]: reset_arr(x, W = 1, T = 0.5)
Out[377]: 
array([ 0.06821936,  0.66300942,  0.15449635,  1.52260898,  0.41346868,
        0.        ,  0.45386276,  2.1888203 ,  0.36947105,  0.        ])
```

Comment: Thank you divakar, your approach made the ndimage approach understandable when I originally found such methods quite complicated. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your if clause like this

```
if (any(x[i:i+100:1]) > .05) and any((x[i-100:i+1:1]) < -.05):
```

However you would have to also specify `i` , the index in the vector x, in the definition of vector_recode.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623939/3025412) post seems to have what you want in a more concise way.

Comment: I see, thank you for the lead. I wonder if np.sort() changes the order of the array? In my application, I need to leave the array as is, and just reference 100 neighbors of an element x in the array, regardless of where x is in the array -- and each element in the array will have a turn to be x, as I'm applying `np.vectorize()`

Comment: @ArashHowaida `np.sort()` is not done in place, so unless you store the result of the function, your array will retain its state

Answer (score 1):

Note that Python's `abs()` function accepts NumPy arrays, too, and returns the component-wise result:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> abs(np.array([-5, 1, -3.3, -2, 0, 11]))
array([  5. ,   1. ,   3.3,   2. ,   0. ,  11. ])
```

So does the `>` operator, even if the other operand is a scalar:

```
>>> abs(np.array([0.01, 0.07, -0.07, -0.02, 5])) > 0.05
array([False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

We can plug this into the approach from [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073807/evaluate-k-adjacent-plus-or-minus-elements-within-array/41075857#41075857):

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

def recode_function(data, k, threshold):
    mask = binary_dilation( abs(data) > threshold, np.ones(2 * k + 1) )
    return np.where(mask, data, 0)
```

If you don't care about the sign of zero values, just (component-wise) multiplying mask and data works, too:

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

def recode_function(data, k, threshold):
    mask = binary_dilation( abs(data) > threshold, np.ones(2 * k + 1) )
    return mask * data
```

Comment: Thank you as well das-g, I used your suggestions in the end, I couldn't have done it without you two's expertise.